# "A few years from now" / "in a few years"

Tags: sentence-meaning, word-order

> **A few years from now**, he’ll probably be married.
>
> He’ll probably be married **in a few years**.

The sentences in their meaning are completely the same, right?

Is it possible to swap them?

> **In a few years**, he’ll probably be married.
>
> He’ll probably be married **a few years from now**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the sentences:

> - A few years from now, he’ll probably be married.

> - He’ll probably be married in a few years.

> - In a few years, he’ll probably be married.

> - He’ll probably be married a few years from now.

are grammatically valid. All are reasonably natural, and a fluent speaker might well say any of them. They all have much the same meaning, the choice is one of style and perhaps emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same.  I can see no difference in meaning or register between them.